# Getting org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException on a TestNGTests

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, testng

I am getting org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException from my TestNG TestClases.

I have extended my TestNG test class with AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests. One of my Test Object has a Lazy collection, which leads to this exception.

Is there any way to make all the collection initialized eagerly during Testing only. This exception does not occur if i do normal execution (No Test).

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke your DAO/Services/Controllers directly (without MockMVC or RestAssured), then just mark the test as `@Transactional`. That way the transactions and the Hibernate Session is going to be opened before the test as well as closed after the test.

Otherwise it's opened by your service and is closed by the service.

Comment: I have used @Transactional,  but the issue is with the object initialized in another Test Class. When i try to access the lazy Collection from another Test Class.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Objects needed for test1 must be created in test1. And in general the order of the tests must not change the results.